# Auth::login() dont work in laravel with driver sqlsrv

Tags: php, laravel

I have been stuck for several days with a problem, I am unable to authenticate a user in a Laravel 8.x project using the sqlsrv driver. Before mentioning all the details I will tell you.

1. The Laravel project is version 8.x.
2. The SQL Server I am connecting to is version 2017 Express.
3. The php version I'm using is 8.2.0.
4. Add the extensions (extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_82_ts_x64
   extension=php_sqlsrv_82_ts_x64) in the php.ini file.
5. The connection from Laravel to SQL Server is correct (because it returns data to me).

Now the code:

- config\database file:

> ```
> 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'),
> 'connections' => [
>   'sqlite' => [...],
>   'mysql' => [...],
>   'pgsql' => [...],
>   'sqlsrv' => [
>       'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
>       'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
>       'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
>       'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
>       'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
>       'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
>       'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
>       'charset' => 'utf8',
>       'prefix' => '',
>       'prefix_indexes' => true,
>   ],
> ],
> ```

- .env

> ```
> DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
> DB_HOST=PC01\SQLEXPRESS
> DB_PORT=1433
> DB_DATABASE=SOLUCION
> DB_USERNAME=sa
> DB_PASSWORD=miclave
> ```

- config/auth file:

> ```
> 'providers' => [
>     'users' => [
>         'driver' => 'eloquent',
>         'model' => App\Models\Usuario::class,
>     ],
> ],
> ```

- app/Models/Usuario file:

> ```
> <?php
>
> namespace App\Models;
>
> use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
> use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
> use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
> use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
> use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
>
> class Usuario extends Authenticatable
> {
>     use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
>
>     protected $table = 'TB__USUARIO';
>
>     protected $fillable = [
>         'ID',
>         'NOMBRE',
>         'CLAVE',
>         'ESTA_ACTIVO'
>     ];
>
>     protected $casts = [
>         'ID' => 'integer',
>         'NOMBRE' => 'string',
>         'CLAVE' => 'string',
>         'ESTA_ACTIVO' => 'boolean'
>     ];
> }
> ```

- app/Http/Controllers/SistemaController file:

> ```
> <?php
>
> namespace App\Http\Controllers;
>
> use Illuminate\Http\Request;
> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
> use App\Models\Usuario;
>
> class SistemaController extends Controller
> {
>     public function login(Request $request) {
>         $usuario = Usuario::where([
>             ['NOMBRE', '=', $request->get('usuario')],
>             ['CLAVE', '=', $request->get('clave')],
>             ['ESTA_ACTIVO', '=', true]
>         ])->first();
>
>         if ($usuario != null) {
>             Auth::login($usuario); // This statement is not working, because if I then do dd(Auth::id()) -> it returns null when it should return the user ID
>
>             $request->session()->regenerate();
>             return redirect()->intended('/pedido');
>         }
>
>         return back()->withErrors([
>             'clave' => 'LAS CREDENCIALES SON INCORRECTAS',
>         ]);
>     }
> }
> ```

- I have printed the variable $usuario (with this command dd($usuario)) to see if it has a value and this is the result.

[image]

In other words, my $usuario variable does have a value, but for some reason I can't authenticate the user. I'd appreciate your help.

Greetings.

Comment: This seems to be a problem: `$request->session()->regenerate();`

Comment: What session driver are you using? Are other session data persisting?

Comment: I have tried sessions and if they work correctly, the problem is with auth::login(), when I use auth::attempt I get an error because I don't have the password column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($usuario != null) {
    Auth::login($usuario); 
    $request->session()->regenerate();
    return redirect()->intended('/pedido');
 }
```

can you try this:

```
if (Auth::attempt($usuario)) {
        dd($usuario); //check if it returns the user ID.
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        return redirect()->intended('/pedido');
    }
```